# Recurrence Relation Quicksort

Tags: recurrence

I've been looking into reccurence relations for quicksort, and I can follow how they get to the final recurrence relation, but then they jump to a time order. For example:

```
T(N) = T(N-1) + T(0)+ Theta(sqrt(N))
```

Then they jump to the time order of: `O(Nsqrt(N))`

I don't follow how they got from the recurrence relation to the time order...

Comment: Basically, you just guess the correct answer and then prove you're correct.

Comment: But I am curious about the steps.

Answer (score 0):

The recurrence relation is not well-defined. You need a boundary condition. Let's assume that `T(1)=1=sqrt(1)` and that `T(0)=0`.

The proof of the fact that `T(N)=O(N*sqrt(N))` is very easy:

```
T(N) = T(N-1) + Theta(sqrt(N)) = T(N-2) + sqrt(N-1) + sqrt(N)
     = ... = sqrt(N) + sqrt(N-1) + ... + sqrt(1)
     <= N * sqrt(N).
```

The bound `<= N*sqrt(N)` obviously holds because `sqrt(1)<...<sqrt(N-1)<sqrt(N)`.

Thus `T(N)=O(N*sqrt(N))`.